# Algorithm to compress a lot of small strings?

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to compress small ASCII strings. They contain lots of letters but they also can contain numbers and rarely special characters. They will be small, about 50-100 bytes average, 250 max.

Examples:

```
Android show EditText.setError() above the EditText and not below it
ImageView CENTER_CROP dont work
Prevent an app to show on recent application list on android kitkat 4.4.2
Image can't save validable in android
Android 4.4 SMS - Not receiving sentIntents
Imported android-map-extensions version 2.0 now my R.java file is missing
GCM registering but not receiving messages on pre 4.0.4. devices
```

I want to compress the titles one by one, not many titles together and I don't care much about CPU and memory usage.

Comment: Text lends itself to zip compression pretty well, you might want to do that, it is available as standalone as well as a part of few libraries.

Comment: Searching for [compression library](https://www.google.com/search?q=compression+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) should give you something to start with.

Comment: I want to compress the titles one by one, not many titles together.

Comment: @luka - you can use zip compression on a single file, in fact it doesn't even need to be a file, you can compress directly a byte array in memory.

Comment: I tried this, it makes the title larger

Comment: @Luka: thats the nature of compression algorithms, some input gets smaller, some input gets larger.

Comment: I also tried this: https://github.com/antirez/smaz/tree/master but doesn't work with capitals

Comment: Compressing a small quantity of data rarely achieves a result better (smaller) than the original input, due to the overhead of the additional header, instructing how the compressed data should be decoded. You can apply a proprietary (your own) method for this specific case. You have 52 letters, 10 digits and space. 63 symbols altogether. You can encode each symbol using 7 bits (instead of 8). The first bit will always be 0, and the remaining 6 bits will be mapped to any of your 63 symbols. For any "non regular symbol", use 1 followed by the ASCII code of that symbol (i.e., 9 bits instead of 8)

Comment: Not usually the best solution, but in this case... You could build a Hoffman compression table from a set of typical titles, then use Hoffman compression using this table for each title.

Comment: Here is how to do it in Qt: `QString blabla("blabalbalblabla lab ablablalba blablalba blablalb alblalb alba lba"); QByteArray bc = qCompress(blabla.toUtf8(), 9); qDebug() << blabla.size() << bc.size();` and as the output suggests, the length of the string has been reduced from 66 to 43 bytes.

Comment: How much space you believe this will save?

Comment: I don't want to use a tool like Qt

Comment: I recommend looking at Huffman Encoding. This will require a tree data structure which stores how each character is encoded. The strings themselves are then stored using single bits in a compressed form. You could either have a separate tree per string but in your case that's an example where you want to have a single tree for multiple strings. So you can compress and uncompress them separately once you "fix" the tree structure. Typically the tree structure depends on the statistics of occurrences in texts, so you need a set of strings for reference when constructing the tree.

Comment: Huffman coding will lead to typically half the size if you apply it character-wise. You can also apply it syllable-wise or word-wise leading to a possibly better per-string compression but a larger tree and slower en- and decoding. Here's the wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding -- To emphasize it again: You will only gain much from this method if you share the same tree between all strings. This requires to know in advance the full character set (i.e. all 127 ASCII symbols have to occur) to be generically reusable among strings not known at tree construction time.

Comment: @Luka - Qt itself uses zlib, I am pretty sure zlib is available in the NDK too. Only the syntax will differ. But don't expect miracles, as James mentioned, small data doesn't compress a lot in zip.

Comment: I am not experience about compression but your solution seems pretty good. If I have thousands of strings and compress them one by one, this might work. Do you have a working example or something close to what I am trying to do

Comment: @Luka I don't know with whom you were talking to in your last comment. If it was me: I added the wikipedia link which contains useful information. I think it's one of the easiest types of entropy encoding (aka compression) which you can implement by yourself. Sharing the tree among all strings is the key to efficient compressions for small strings (even single words can be compressed very well)

Comment: Yes, it was you, thanks a lot, I will check this out.

Comment: @leemes - I've done something similar to Huffman's method before, but not based on frequency and single characters - every string is decomposed into separate words, which are decomposed into separate characters. So a string is actually an array of words and a word is an array of characters. This way you can use the minimum width value to express any character or word from the character and word sets. For example if you have less than 256 unique words you can use a single byte to express each of them. A sentence of 10 words will then be 10 bytes, regardless of the words length.

Comment: If I have millions of words, I guess I am out of luck?

Comment: The idea to extend Huffman encoding by substrings like syllables or whole words is to compress whole words in a few bits. If the table/tree needs to be computed without knowing the strings (and then hardcoding it into the application), this would require a statistical analysis of the language to be used, i.e. very common english words will appear in the tree, as well as common syllables, and we still need all ASCII characters in order to "fall back" to single chars for unlisted words. Compressing strings is then a bit more complicated since there might be ambiguities, e.g. `"and" = "an" + "d"`

Comment: No, I don't need the table hardcoded, but more strings will be added as time goes on

Comment: Hm, you can choose very common words and insert them into the table as whole words, so they will be encoded using few bits. It's only a matter of efficiency what happens with the other words. What I want to say is that unlisted words can still be encoded, but by splitting them into syllables or single characters. The original Huffman encoding encodes single characters; the idea to extend this to words is an improvement.

Comment: @leemes - yes, for unknown at runtime scenarios you will probably not want to use bitfields, keep it to bytes for the individual characters, and for the words you can use a `short`, I doubt the vocabulary will extend past `2^16-1` words.

Comment: If you can even change the table/tree from time to time (from version to version, or by providing a file), you can improve the compression from time to time. What you also want is a little program which computes the table for you (which is then run once on your "typical" set of strings). Using the table you can then en- and decode texts.

Comment: I believe it will extend 2^16-1. If one writes: 'PS3' and another one 'ps3' those are two different things. If another writes 'Playstation 3' it's another word

Comment: @ddriver The idea of Huffman is to have dynamic length encoding for different probabilities of occurrences. That means, `"and it is here"` is probably using a lot less bits (e.g. 4 + 3 + 4 + 5 bits) than a string composed of four other words occuring less frequent in the language (or in the reference set of strings, wherever they come from). That also means that (which is the case for all compressions) there can be inputs which expand in their length, maybe something like `"q.!q$?"`, since it contains very seldomly occuring characters.

Comment: But my approach allows for every "word" to exist intact a single time in memory and be fetched directly from its address without any decompression, from a hash function using its characters. Also, entire strings / sentences can also be represented with a single token if repeated. Also, no need to mangle with bits and stuff.

Comment: @ddriver OP asked for a good compression and doesn't care about performance. I know however that handling single bits can be painful, but there are some bitstream helper classes simplifying this kind of stuff.

Comment: @leemes - you can perfectly size each token according to its frequency of occurrence as in Hoffman's approach, the difference would be you don't only compress in one pass, e.g. characters, but then apply the same approach when working with next level tokens, e.g. words. This will severely decrease size, because now you are not just saving on frequently reused characters, but also entire words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [*Huffman coding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) with a shared Huffman tree among all texts you want to compress.

While you typically construct a Huffman tree for each string to be compressed separately, this would require a lot of overhead in storage which should be avoided here. That's also the major problem when using a standard compression scheme for your case: most of them have some overhead which kills your compression efficiency for very short strings. Some of them don't have a (big) overhead but those are typically less efficient in general.

When constructing a Huffman tree which is later used for compression and decompression, you typically use the texts which will be compressed to decide which character is encoded with which bits. Since in your case the texts to be compressed seem to be unknown in advance, you need to have some "pseudo" texts to build the tree, maybe from a dictionary of the human language or some experience of previous user data.

Then construct the Huffman tree and store it once in your application; either hardcode it into the binary or provide it in the form of a file. Then you can compress and decompress any texts using this tree. Whenever you decide to change the tree since you gain better experience on which texts are compressed, the compressed string representation also changes. It might be a good idea to introduce versioning and store the tree version together with each string you compress.

Another improvement you might think about is to use multi-character Huffman encoding. Instead of compressing the texts character by character, you could find frequent syllables or words and put them into the tree too; then they require even less bits in the compressed string. This however requires a little bit more complicated compression algorithm, but it might be well worth the effort.

To process a string of bits in the compression and decompression routine *in C++*<sup>(*)</sup>, I recommend either [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) or [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Both internally pack multiple bits into bytes.

---

<sup>(*)</sup><sub>The question once had the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, so OP obviously wanted to implement it in C++. But as the general problem is not specific to a programming language, the tag was removed. But I still kept the C++-specific part of the answer.</sub>