# fastest way to store an int in part of byte?

Tags: c++

First of all this is not homework. In one compression algorithm I am trying to make I need to store stuff this way:

I want to store a number from 0 to 2^10-1.

Normally one will store this number by consuming 16 bits. I don't want this. Another sane person will say: fine, use the first 10 bits. I don't want this.

I want to store the number like this: use 5 bits, 3 bits empty, use 5 bits, 3 bits empty.

How to do this pretty fast without creating the risk of nasty bugs?

Comment: You'll need to be a little more clear about what you want. I can't understand what you need and what the problem is. Maybe give an example of what you'd like to be able to do?

Comment: I want to have the last 3 bits of each byte empty, so I can store 0 or 1 there without affecting the value of the number

Comment: @C.B: That's why I use two 5 bits

Comment: I'm assuming you have decided that shifting and masking are not adequate

Comment: Wouldn't using a bit mask operator suffice?

Comment: What is the rational for this?

Comment: I want to save space and by doing this I can save some bits in some cases.

Comment: I think Boolean operations are the fastest thing you can get. (In case your target processor doesn't have slow logic operations , but this is highly unlikely )

Comment: @Luka - But the code is going to eat it up. Also computer memory is cheap. Disk space is very cheap

Comment: cheap yes, but when you try to compress something, you try to make is as small as possible

Comment: @luka - Why? It is a trade off between small and ease of use. Besides there are plenty of algorithms to compress data out there

Comment: @EdHeal: I am trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's much sense in trying anything else but the obvious way:

```
static inline void store10(uint8_t *out, unsigned short value)
{
  out[0] &= 0xe0;
  out[0] |= (value & 0x1f0) >> 5; // mask not needed if value is in-range.
  out[1] &= 0xe0;
  out[1] |= value & 0x1f;
}
```

Comment: What does your comment mean when it says *"x is in-range"*?  I see no variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = ...;
unsigned char first = x & 0x1f;
unsigned char second = x >> 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short pack10(unsigned short n)
{
    return ((n & 0x3e0)<<6) | ((n & 0x1f)<<3);
}
```